# What problems are javascript callbacks trying to solve?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand what problems javascript callbacks are trying to solve. From what I've read so far, we have events and these events may accept a function as a parameter (callback function)

[reference here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-async)

```
var img1 = document.querySelector('.img-1');

img1.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // woo yey image loaded
});

img1.addEventListener('error', function() {
  // argh everything's broken
});
```

So my guess is that the problem that we are trying to solve is that we want to do more things after the event has occurred?

for example:

Imagine I have a system that contains an input text with a button that searches stores by zip-code, and a single button that searches stores using my geolocation. If i clicked the button to search a store with an input of "12345", I would also expect to "callback" another function that would clear the geolocation; since I don't want that to interfere with my results.

Does that make sense?

Comment: No, your question doesn't make sense. You're better off reading some tutorials about JavaScript and events in general.

Comment: Callbacks provide a generic way to pass instructions to other parts of the system.

Comment: Asynchronicity, to answer your main question. In the example, callbacks are just parameters telling an element what to do in various circumstances.

Comment: Nice explanation here http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are most often used when code needs to be run asynchronously. Synchronous means "in order", so asynchronous means not in order. The nature of asynchronous things is that their order can't be predicted. This is the case with AJAX requests and events, two major aspects of front end development. We can't know how long it will take for a server to respond, and we can't know when users will click buttons and bring up other events, much less know the order in which they'll do it. Therefore we used callbacks to essentially say: "When this asynchronous operation completes, do X", where X is the code in your callback function.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your explanation. As I read more on this subject this is making more sense. Leading to (sounding like) promises.

Answer (score 0):

> What problems are javascript callbacks trying to solve?

This is a reasonable and answerable question. The description gets a bit confusing, and I'm not sure that's exactly what you're looking for, but I'll answer the initial question as posed.

Javascript is not a multithreaded language. In-browser, the page will lock up until Javascript code finishes executing, and NodeJS applications will be unable to serve any other requests or execute any other logic until the code completes.

Callbacks are the workaround for this. They allow the developer to specify code to run on a given event, for instance an AJAX request completing or (in Node) a database query returning data. Without a callback, the page/application would lock until the request is received, which defeats the A (asymmetric) in AJAX.

Further reading:

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: Thanks for that link, I had landed on it just earlier last night after I posted this question. =)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, this is used in asynchronous calls. I'll try to explain it briefly and in a very simple way.
Let's say you are making a call to save the data using Ajax. The actual saving can take some time (let's say 1 second), but the flow of control is moved to the next statement right after the call is made. In other words, your code is not waiting for the response from the method call. (That's because it is asynchronous).
However, you may want to display a message to the user, indicating if the record was saved successfully, or the operation has failed. In this scenario, you need to use the callback method and check the return value of you Ajax call.
You cannot predict when the callback method happens, but when it happens, the code inside the callback gets executed and this is where you can add your logic to display a proper message to the user.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain in your words how this works to me.